# Mark package to never be considered for upgrade

Tags: package

`list-packages` prompts you to upgrade packages when newer versions are available. How do you tell `package.el` to never consider a particular package for auto-upgrades? There are some packages which I have minor customizations for and don't care about newer versions of them.

Comment: Does Emacs *automatically auto-upgrade all packages*? Why should you need to tell it not to automatically upgrade a particular package? (I would hope that users have some control over this.)

Comment: It offers to automatically upgrade packages which have updates available. I like this feature - usually there would be a ton of packages and if the package author put something up on elpa/melpa/marmalade saying there's something new, I would want it. In a handful of cases, I would want to make an exception and say "No, lay off these packages."

Comment: I see. I agree that it should be easy for users to do as you request. Maybe someone will say it is, and tell you how.

Comment: I believe this functionality is referred to as *pinning* in other package managers. I have heard reference to it for `package.el`, but haven't found a description of how to do it.

Comment: @dgtized You can pin the packages to one of the repositories but you can't pin a package to stay put with a local version that doesn't belong to either of the repositories.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Add the following code to your init-file (replace `package-1`, `package-2`, etc. with names of packages you would like to freeze at the current version):

```el
(defvar package-menu-exclude-packages '("package-1" "package-2" "package-n"))

(defun package-menu--remove-excluded-packages (orig)
  (let ((included (-filter
                   (lambda (entry)
                     (let ((name (symbol-name (package-desc-name (car entry)))))
                       (not (member name package-menu-exclude-packages))))
                   tabulated-list-entries)))
    (setq-local tabulated-list-entries included)
    (funcall orig)))

(advice-add 'package-menu--find-upgrades :around #'package-menu--remove-excluded-packages)
```

#### Explanation

`package-menu--find-upgrades` is responsible for building the list of packages to upgrade. To do this, it looks at each entry in `tabulated-list-entries`. So in order to ignore certain packages, we need to:

1. Introduce a variable that holds a list of packages to ignore (called `package-menu-exclude-packages` above).
2. [Advise](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Advising-Functions.html) `package-menu--find-upgrades` to run with a modified version of `tabulated-list-entries` that excludes the packages we'd like to ignore.

Comment: This will be a good addition to the emacs trunk on git.

Comment: No longer works, getting error: `error in process filter: Symbol’s function definition is void: -filter`

Comment: @KeksDose `-filter` is defined in the [`dash` library](https://melpa.org/#/dash), so you'll need to install that before using this snippet.

Comment: @itsjeyd Thank you. Adding  `(require dash)` to .emacs after installing solved the issue.